# Joing two dataframes on matching format function values

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark, format

How to use format function while joining 2 dataframes

Temp=date,product,channel
Temp2=','.join(temp)
Query
Select a *,b.values,b.{temp1} from dataframe1 a left join dataframe b on a.{temp}=b.{temp}

But here it's not working it's taking a.datr, product,channel=b.....
Which is wrong i want to join based on temp values

I have tried the mentioned operation

Comment: Hi! Would you mind providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it's possible to investigate what's going on?